# limit of $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)$ as x tends to 1 (if it exists)

Tags: real-analysis

Hi trying to do a past exam question here and we haven't provided with answers.
The question is to find the limit of the following if it exists:

$f(x)=\cos\biggr(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\biggr) $ as $x\rightarrow 1$

My feeling is that is does not exist but I am not sure how to answer it correctly to say this.
If it does exist any tips on how to get there will be appreciated:)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$ \lim _{x\to 1} \cos(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}) = \lim _{t\to \infty} \cos(t)$$

As t goes to infinity, $\cos(t)$ takes every value between $-1$ and $1$ infinitely many times, and the limit does not exist.

For every large number $M$ there exists an $n>M$ so $\cos(n\pi ) =1$ and there is an $k>M$ for which, $\cos(k\pi)=-1.$
Therefore the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is equivalent to the limit
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\cos(y).$$
This limit cannot exist because no matter how large $y$ is, there exists a $Y>y$ such that
$\cos(Y) = \cos(y+\pi) = -\cos(y).$
So, $|\cos(Y)-\cos(y)| = 2|\cos(y)|$.  From the definition of convergence, this difference of absolute value would need to become arbitrarily small for all $y$ sufficiently large.  Clearly, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined, since there is no indeterminate form -- just $\cos \left(\frac10\right)$, which approaches $\cos (\infty)$. Since $\cos$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$, this limit is undefined.